# Why don't these modified bubble sort algorithms produce the same order in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, list, algorithm, bubble-sort

Objective: to order list by first two characters only, when comparing two elements from a list if they are the same then keep the original order.

**Snippet #1**

```
l= []
for i in range(int(input())):
    l.append(input().split())

    for i, j in enumerate(l):
        for b, c in enumerate(l[:-1]):
            if l[b][:2] > l[b+1][:2]:
                l[b],l[b+1] = l[b+1], l[b]
l = [x[0] for x in l]
print( '\n'.join(str(p) for p in l))
```

The output from #1:
The items are alphabetical when considering the entire text, but I only want to consider the first two characters of each string and compare those. When they are the same, I want the original order of those which were compared.

[image]

**Snippet #2**

```
l = ['Hilbert','Godel','Poincare', 'Ramanujan','Pochhammmer']
for i, j in enumerate(l):
    for b, c in enumerate(l[:-1]):
        if l[b][:2] > l[b+1][:2]:
            l[b],l[b+1] = l[b+1], l[b]
#l = [x[0] for x in l]
print( '\n'.join(str(p) for p in l))
```

Output from #2:
This output is what I was expecting.

[image]

Comment: What part of either snippet imposes any particular ordering if the the first 2 characters are the same?

Comment: @ScottHunter even if I did something like this the result is inconsistent:

def first_letters(word):
    return word[:2]

l= []  
for i in range(int(input())):
    l.append(input().split())
    
    r = sorted(l, key=first_letters, reverse=False)
print(r)

Comment: What part of your code is intended to eliminate this "inconsistency"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first algorithm when you use .split() you create a list of lists. So your variable (l) is equal to :
[['Hilbert'], ['Godel'], ['Poincare'], ['Ramanujan'], ['Pochammer']]
(sorry if I misspelled)
so when you ask l[b][:2] you are asking for the first two elements of the list ['Poincare'] which is the list in position b of your initial list, and it is equal to ['Poincare']. So when it gets to ['Poincare'] > ['Pochammer'] it gives 'True'.
Given that your lists are composed of only one element (ex. ['Hilbert']) it is able to sort them in the right way and the only problem is with ['Poincare'] - ['Pochammer']
Next time just do not use .split() in this situation but try with l.append(input('')). The .split() is better used for something like 'A B C D E'.split() or something like that.